# How do I generate N counters inside a generate block to load test an FPGA?

Tags: verilog, counter, xilinx, quartus, intel-fpga

I need to estimate the maximum number of 16-bit counters that a FPGA board can fit. I created a 16-bit counter module with enable (`en`) and terminal count (`TC`), and instantiated this inside a `generate` block in a top level module. However, I need to generate these counters in a chain where the `TC` output of one acts as the enable for the next counter in the chain. I'm unable to figure out the logic for this. Can anyone help me ?

16-bit counter code:

```
module counter_16 (clk, Q, TC, en);

input clk, en;
output [15:0] Q;
output TC;

wire clk, en;
reg [15:0] Q = 0; //initial value for the output count
reg TC;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if(en == 1)
    begin
        Q <= Q+1;
    end
    TC = &Q; //TC is 1 when all bits of Q is high
end

endmodule
```

Counter generation module:

```
module counter_generator
#(
    parameter n = 10
)
(output [15:0] cnt_out,
output TC,
input clk, en);

wire [n-1:0] temp_en;
temp_en[0] <= 0;
wire [15:0] temp_out;

generate 
    genvar i;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i=i+1)
    begin : counter_identifier
        counter_16 counter_16_gen (
        .clk(clk), 
        .Q(temp_out), 
        .TC(temp_en[i-1]), 
        .en(en));
    end
endgenerate 
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is make the loop start from 0, not 1, so that the signal indexes align.

Create a signal `tc_out` that is `n` bits wide and connect that directly to the `TC` port in the generate block, using the index `[i]`.  `TC` of instance 0 is connected to `tc_out[0]`, etc.  This is straightforward, and it helps us with the `en` connections.

Create a signal `temp_en` that is also `n` bits wide and connect that directly to the `en` port in the generate block.  The key is to assign this signal to the `tc_out` signal as seen below.

- `en` of instance 0 is driven by the `en` input of `counter_generator`
- `en` of instance 1 is driven by the `TC` output of instance 0
- `en` of instance 2 is driven by the `TC` output of instance 1
- etc.

Lastly, create an array of `n` 16-bit wires, `temp_out`, and connect that directly to the `Q` port in the generate block.

---

```
module counter_generator
#(
    parameter n = 10
)
(
output [15:0] cnt_out,
output TC,
input clk, en
);

  wire [n-1:0] tc_out;
  wire [n-1:0] temp_en = {tc_out[n-2:0], en};
  wire [15:0]  temp_out [n];
  assign TC = temp_out[n-1];

generate 
  genvar i;
  for (i=0; i<n; i=i+1) begin : counter_identifier
        counter_16 counter_16_gen (
          .clk  (clk), 
          .Q    (temp_out[i]),
          .TC   (tc_out  [i]), 
          .en   (temp_en [i])
        );
  end
endgenerate 
endmodule
```